# "complete-tag" can't find TAGS file

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I would like to use:

- "etags-select" to navigate in source code
- "complete-tag" (from emacs etag.el) to complete input text.

I have this in my .emacs

```
(setq-default tags-table-list '("../TAGS"))
```

"etags-select" works correctly looking for TAGS file **one** step up in the directory tree, but complete-tag looks **two** steps up and can't find TAGS file.

Some more information:

Working in **C:/projects/root/v16/src/**, I invoke "complete-tag" and Emacs show me (in Minibuffer):

Visit tags table (default TAGS): **C:/projects/root/v16/**

That is the correct directory (one step up in tree). Now I push enter and Emacs answers:

**C:/projects/root/TAGS** is not a valid tags table

That is a wrong directory, one more step up.

Comment: Dunno why, but as a workaround, can you set a buffer-local TAGS file with an absolute path?

Comment: I need the project to be fully portable. Anyway I will take this workaround  in account when no other solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I solved a similar issue by using environment variables: I happened to have an environment variable pointing to the root of my current project, so I reused it for building the name of the tags table (so I never ran into problems with relative paths).

If that is not your case, I would try [etags-table](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/etags-table.el).  You can setup a regexp, or you can set `etags-table-search-up-depth` to a value that works for you.

Both approaches leave your hands free for adding directory levels to your projects.

Comment: Thanks. Using etags-table and etags-table-search-up-depth set to 1, it can find TAGS file without information in my .emacs

Answer (score 1):

The variable you are using, tags-table-list, is a list.  You can put in that list both "../TAGS" and "TAGS".  This should work for the setup you describe.

Comment: I have tried it. Both tables must exist and  be valid. When "TAGS" is the first item in the list, "complete-tags" works and loads both tables. When the first item is "../TAGS", "complete-tags" fails as before.
Plus, due to the dual tables, "etags-select" doubles the 
proposed chances.